# using css not selector in meteor template event handler

Tags: jquery, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to apply class `inactive` to all input elements which have type not equals to `date`.
It is not applying the class. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

```js
  'focus input[type="date"]': function() {
    $('input').not([type = "date"]).addClass('inactive');
  },
```

Comment: `.not("[type = date]")` try this

Comment: @guradio yes. Thanks